# PHP-SQLSRV Stored Procedure with input variable of type `bit`

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have to port a LAMP-based project that uses PHP-MSSQL to connect to a SQL Server db.  It has to be ported to a WAMP-based machine that uses PHP-SQLSRV to connect to a SQL Server db.

I can get/set data by executing stored procedures.  It seems like most types of input variables are pretty simple to get working.  But I cannot get input params of type `bit` to work.

I have tried using various values in PHP that are 'truthy' or 'falsey', but non of them get me past the error:

- 'truthy' things that didn't work:

  - `1`
  - `"1"`
  - `true`
  - `"True"`
- 'falsey' things that didn't work:

  - `0`
  - `"0"`
  - `false`
  - `"False"`

I have tried using various ways to add an item to the `$params` array, including omitting optional arguments as well as defining the PHP and SQL data types.  Nothing works.

My error message from SQL Server (converted to a JSON object) is:

```
[{
  "0":"42000",
  "SQLSTATE":"42000",
  "1":8114,
  "code":8114,
  "2":"[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to bit.",
  "message":"[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to bit."
}]
```

To generate this error message, I passed a value of `0` or `1`, neither of which is a `varchar` or even a string.

To maintain maximum compatibility I do not want to alter the Stored Procedure to Cast/Convert data on SQL Server.  I want this to work from PHP keeping Stored Procedure unchanged.

---

PHP code:

```
<?php
  $link = sqlsrv_connect($host,Array("Database"=>$database,"UID"=>$username,"PWD"=>$password));
  $sql = " { call StoredProcedureName ( @input_param_of_bit_type=? ) } ";
  $param1 = 1;
  $params = Array(
    Array(&$param1, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
  );
  $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($link,$sql,$params);
  if ($stmt===false) {
    // handle error
    print_r(sqlsrv_errors,true);
  } else {
    if (sqlsrv_execute($stmt)===false) {
      // handle error.  This is where the error happens
      print_r(sqlsrv_errors,true);
    } else {
      // success! It never gets here, though.
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Might have to modify the queries to include a `CAST(0 AS BIT)` to force the bit datatype.

Comment: @Marc B: actual SQL query lives in Stored Procedure on SQL Server.  I want to keep Stored Procedures unchanged.

Comment: Please post the calling PHP, the problem probably lies there, especially if you're parameterizing your proc call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-ordering the order of the named parameters made this work.  I had to use SQL Server Management Studio software and Profile Tracing to see what was different about executing the Stored Procedure from php-sqlsrv vs. executing it directly from within SQL Server Management Studio.

After I put the input parameters in the exact order used by SQL Server Management Studio, everything worked OK.

Answer (score 0):

The appears to be that the T-SQL above is using the default string type, which is being sent to the server in a way that won’t convert.  The best fix is to specify the PHPTYPE and SQLTYPE in the parameter:

`$params = Array( 
    Array(&$param1, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_INT, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_BIT) 
  );`

Please try that change and see if your query executes correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: Tried this, but it made no difference.  I can execute other Stored Procedures using named parameters.  It is just the Stored Procedures that have input params that are of type bit that cause the error.

Comment: I have tried this, but there error is still occurring.  Can you verify that I haven't found a bug in php-sqlsrv?  That is, can you execute a Stored Procedure that takes an input param of type `bit`?